# Adding a custom view inside a UItableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom view which also contains a UIButton. I use this view inside an `UITableView` cell to act like an animated button on the right side.

My issue is that even when I click on the table view cell, the custom view hit event is also triggered.

Why is this happening ? And how can fix this ?

Comment: " the custom view hit event is also triggered." You mean the button?

Comment: yes, the button, inside the custom view.

Comment: So you want tap on the button to do one action, and a tap on the cell *outside* the button to do some other action?

Comment: How have you implemented the actions? `@IBAction`s connected in the xib/storyboard, or `- addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` calls to the button in code?

Comment: I managed to fix it. Thanks. It was a problem with the IBAction event.